# reading CSV through JAVA

Tags: java

Can anyone tell whats the best way of reading a CSV file. The file I am trying to read is nearly 23 MB so it's a taking a lot of time to read the lines through buffered reader:

```
BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("HostSystems.csv"));
String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
while (dataRow != null){   
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");  
    for (String item:dataArray) {       
        System.out.print(item + "\t");   
    }            

    System.out.println(); // Print the data line.   
    dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
}
```

Is there another efficient way?

Comment: Sorry for the bad code schema.

Comment: thanks for the Link....but can you tell me whts the best for a CSV file with more than 40k entries.....may be more. I just want the code to read the data fast.

Comment: A link to the duplicate answer would be helpful, here, if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do not run out of memory and go fast, you need to go down to `java.nio`. There are plenty questions in here that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`opencsv`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or `JSefa` (to convert it into xml).